# when I wrote this code in my project but the version of firebase_messaging is ^9.1.2 so anyone can tell me what i can change to run correctly

Tags: flutter, messaging

```
 Future initialize(context) async {
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getNotificationSettings(
      
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((Map<String, dynamic> message))  async {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
         getRideRequestId(message);
        retrieveRideRequestInfo(getRideRequestId(message), context);
      },
    
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of on Message use :

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
  print('Message data: ${message.data}');

  if (message.notification != null) {
    print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
  }
});
```

for background message

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Note background message is handled in separate isolate if you are using firebase you have to initialise it first to use it.

Reference:

Foreground:https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#foreground-messages
Background:https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages